# What does "foo" stand for in this PostGIS command?

Tags: postgis, sql

The [help page for the PostGIS function ST_PixelAsCentroids](http://postgis.net/docs/RT_ST_PixelAsCentroids.html) has this line of code as a usage example:
`SELECT x, y, val, ST_AsText(geom) FROM (SELECT (ST_PixelAsCentroids(rast, 1)).* FROM dummy_rast WHERE rid = 2) foo;`

What is the word "foo" standing in for in this example?

Comment: Additional details on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar

Answer (score 10, accepted):

'foo' is the name that has been assigned to the sub-selection. It has no function other than being syntactically necessary - a sub-selection in PostgreSQL must have a name assigned to it, but it does not matter what the name is. 'foo' was likely chosen because it is a common meaningless placeholder word used by programmers, similar to 'lorem ipsum' used by designers.

Comment: So if I put "AS" before "foo" it would do the same thing? Can I always omit "AS" like that?

Comment: Yes. Tech on the Net has a good explanation: "AS is optional. Most programmers will specify the AS keyword when aliasing a column name, but not when aliasing a table name. Whether you specify the AS keyword or not has no impact on the alias in PostgreSQL. It is a personal choice in PostgreSQL, unlike other databases." -- http://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/alias.php

Comment: For more information about "foo" and other "metasyntactic variables", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable and http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/M/metasyntactic-variable.html